# VS2015 Source Code Mapping with IIS Test Cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, codelens, browser-testing

Visual Studio 2015 shows test names on top of function as shown 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJymD.png) for unit tests. This doesn't work for browser based tests that run on an ASP.NET web site running under IIS.

Is there any way or setting to show names of such test cases on top of functions just like unit test cases in C#?

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript unit testing? https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/12/01/javascript-unit-testing-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Thanks Lex for the reply, we are looking for the test cases written in c#. (updated the question)